# Using pca Crashes Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, pca, face-recognition

For this problem, I do not understand why my MATLAB crashes every time I run my pca line.  I am using pca on a matrix containing the anomalous faces as described below:

pics.mat contains a matrix data of 40 images each with dimensions of 96*64 pixels. (a matrix of 96*64*40)

[image]

My code for this section is:

```
%% problem 1a: finding average face
load('pics.mat'); % loads the file

% combines the 3d matrix into a 2d matrix
total = [pics(:, :, 1)]; 
for i = 2:40
    total = [total + pics(:, :, i)];
end

size(total) %96 by 64
A1 = total/40 % the average values divided by total # of faces for avg face


%% problem 1b: the anomalous face
Anom = [];

for i = 1:40
    Anom(:, :, i) = [pics(:, :, i) - A1]; % subtract the average face from all 40 images
end
```

What I am having trouble with is when I do this section which involves using pca on the 40 anomalous faces from part b, my MATLAB crashes.

[image]

My code for this section is:

```
%% problem 1c I: pca
Anom = reshape(Anom, [6144 40]); % reshapes a 3d into 2d

[eigenfaces,scores,sigma2] = pca(Anom', 'Centered' ,'off'); % this crashes MATLAB
```

Why is this crashing? Is it because of my code from the earlier sections or is it because of the fact that I am running this on an extremely anemic laptop?

Comment: Is it a 64bit OS?  If not, you might want to check memory consumption of matlab.exe right after the crash - even from task manager.

Comment: Most likely you have a "weak" computer and the code is too much for Matlab. Matlab does not usually crash for errors in the code.

Comment: Yeah, I am running this on a Windows 8 64bit. It's probably the memory; I tried pca on a much smaller matrix and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where dimensionality makes the calculation overwhelming.
[This link of Cootes](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/research/imag/courses/Kokkinos/asm_overview.pdf) Active Shape Models, in Appendix C he transform his D to T to cope with matrix dimensionality.

I hope it could be applicable in your case too because it saved me from a lot of trouble.

This is how I solved it in MatLab:

imvecs = a vector of images

meanval = their mean value

size(imvecs,2) = the number of images in my data set (N)

```
function [T, D] = covarianceMatrix(imvecs, meanval)
    D = [];
    for i = 1:size(imvecs,2),
       diff = imvecs{i} - meanval;
       D = [D, diff];
    end
    %Dimensionality reduction
    T = (D' * D) ./ (size(imvecs,2));
return
```

T is now a NxN sized matrix, which is hopefully easier to calculate without running out of memory.

Good luck!